# How to find the data which relatd to dropdown selected value asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to fil the book ISBN on text box which matched with the Title selected on Dropdown menu. Please advice me how to proceed me ...

Comment: Can you please show the table schema properly? Your first table schema says table `Books` has Title & ISBN as columns but in your sqldatasource you are fetching data from `Title` table.

Comment: @RahulSingh: hi rahul i have updated

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by matched with title selected? Match with what? Do you want to show the `ISBN` no. on textbox when user select any option?

Comment: You can change SQL query to select ISBN as well and use that in dropdownlist value field , and on dropdown select change , set text box value  = dropdown list selected value. IF you need help with code, i can post that.

Comment: @RahulSingh : what i want is if a user select a Title , matching ISBN number for that Title should display on ISBN text box field. Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to change your mark-up like this:-

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
       DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Book_Title"
       DataValueField="isbn"     OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Text="Select Book" Value="" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
          ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Knowledge_CenterConnectionString %>"
         SelectCommand="select Book_Title,isbn from Title"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="ISBN"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtISBN" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Then simply on dropdownlist selected index change event bind the value to textbox:-

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtISBN.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
}
```

Comment: I want to dropdown menu to diplay only titles. Once a title seelct only matching ISBN value should passed to Text box . please advice

Comment: @mahimachand - You said: i want is if a user select a Title , matching ISBN number for that Title should display on ISBN text box field. That is what this code does. What is matching ISBN value? Match with what?

Comment: Ex: if user select Title as "abc " which was book title , and txtISBN should display ISBN number of that book. Like when select the value and click submit button txtISBN text box should display its ISBN value

Comment: @mahimachand - That is what this code is doing, we have ISBN number as value field and book title as text field so only that will be displayed on the screen. When user selects any book from drop down, the ISBN no associated with that book will be displayed in textbox. Have u tried this code?